# Android open the directory of a uri obtained through ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: android, uri

I am using Android [`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#create-file) to select a location to save a PDF file.
After getting the `uri` and writing to the file (as done in the code below), I want to show a `Snackbar` with the action set to opening the *location* of the file.

To be clear I don't want to open the file itself, but to help user locate the file using the file explorer app. Is there a "developer.android.com" recommended way to do this? The current code is as follows.

```
private void getSaveLocation() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "MyFile.pdf");
    startActivityForResult(intent, MY_CODE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || data == null || data.getData() == null) return;

    Uri uri = data.getData();
    OutputStream out = getContext().getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
    // write the pdf to out

    try {
        out.close();
        showSnackbar(uri);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void showSnackbar(Uri uri) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Saved to MyFile.pdf", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    snackbar.setAction("Locate file", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            // NEED TO SETUP THE INTENT CORRECTLY USING uri
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a "developer.android.com" recommended way to do this?

No.

First, there is no standard "open a file explorer on a particular location" `Intent` action.

Second, there is no requirement that `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` be used to open a document that is part of something that can be explored. The user can use it to access documents in other things (encrypted containers, cloud storage, etc.) that may not necessarily be accessible by a file manager.

Answer (score 0):

ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT gives you an uri for a file and read write permissions for this file if you use the uri.

Even if you would manage to decode an uri for the parent directory you would not be able to use that uri as read and write permissions would lack.